# CSS3 Making :before content not highlightable

Tags: html, css, web

== FIXED BY CHROME IN VERSION 60.0.3112.90 ==

-CHROME BUG-

bug reported: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=703807&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=

Okay, so I've been working on a project that has CSS line numbers. When users highlight/select text the numbers get highlighted/selected as well. Luckily the :before content doesn't get copied with it, but it still annoys me. Is there any way to fix this.

Notes: Pre is contenteditable='true'

What I have tried:

```
user-select: none;
```

AS WELL AS

```
pre code:before::selection {

    background: transparent;

}
```

This is some example code:

```
<pre contenteditable='true'><code>bla</code><code>bla</code><code>bla</code></pre>

<style>
    pre {
        margin: 0px;
        outline: none;
    }

    pre code {
        display: block;
        color: #a9b7c6;
        counter-increment: line;
    }

    pre code:before {
        content: '\00a0'counter(line)'\00a0';
        margin-right: 2px;
        border-right: solid #4b4b4b 1px;
    }
</style>
```

What it looks like now:

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

Comment: i think that before actually makes element unselectable. how is it opposite in your case

Comment: I have absolutely no idea, the text copy function works fine but the look is irritating.

Comment: Chrome bug report link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=703807&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have included an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question. It is now not clear what goes wrong. I cannot reproduce your problem, please see the below snippet.

Note that having the `pre` be [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) does not combine very well with having every line be a separate `code` element. I am assuming that you are handling this via JavaScript? Or am I misunderstanding what you do?

In any case, the below (that does not even use `user-select: none`) seems to work for me (in Firefox <s>and Chrome</s>, screenshot is taken in Firefox).

[image: Selection does not include <code>:before</code> elements.]

```css
pre, code {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

pre {
  font-size: 0;
}

pre code {
  counter-increment: line;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

pre code:before {
  content: counter(line)".";
  margin-right: .5rem;
  padding-right: .2rem;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<pre contenteditable="true">
  <code>a line 1</code>
  <code>a line 2</code>
  <code>a line 3</code>
  <code>a line 4</code>
  <code>a line 5</code>
  <code>a line 6</code>
</pre>
```

---

**Edit.** I can actually reproduce the issue in Chrome. It looks like only the counter is highlighted by the selection, any other content is not. That is, in the below snippet, the dot is not highlighted. If I replace the `content: counter(line)"."` with, say, `content: "1."`, then the selection ignores the pseudo-elements as expected. The counter is always selected. It is not impacted by styling of [`::selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection) either. This smells like a bug in Chrome to me - although nothing is guaranteed about text selection in the CSS spec of course (`user-select` and `::selection` are both only in the draft for [CSS4-UI](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#propdef-user-select))... But text in pseudo-elements should really not be selectable.

You could [open a bug report](http://dev.chromium.org/for-testers/bug-reporting-guidelines). See what they say.

The only thing I can offer you is a workaround. Hope it still helps. It puts the line numbers in a completely separate element. The line numbers now need to be maintained using JavaScript. Since you state that you already have scripts in place to handle editing, I figured why not script this too?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.editor {
  position: relative;
}

html {
  font-size: 18px; /* define font size for rem */
}

pre {
  padding-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 0;
}

pre code {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
}

lines {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

line {
  display: block;
  padding-right: .2rem;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
  
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="editor">
  <pre contenteditable="true">
    <code>a line 1</code>
    <code>a line 2</code>
    <code>a line 3</code>
    <code>a line 4</code>
    <code>a line 5</code>
    <code>a line 6</code>
  </pre>
  <lines>
    <line>1.</line>
    <line>2.</line>
    <line>3.</line>
    <line>4.</line>
    <line>5.</line>
    <line>6.</line>
  </lines>
</div>
```

Comment: I have many handlers for the pre and code tags in javascript and must be in a content editable main tag. Here's a screenshot from the newest version of chrome.
http://imgur.com/a/7mTZE
Could this possibly be a removal of user-select in browsers?

Comment: @DrBrad Your screenshot is not from my answer, is it? I am positive that `user-select` is not removed from the CSS specification.

Comment: Sadly it's from your answer.

Comment: @DrBrad Right, I was confused by the dark theme. I'm on mobile now, will take a closer look later.

Comment: That's my extension I made a while back haha. Thank you

Comment: @DrBrad I have edited my answer. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Thank you, the work around sadly wont work for what my plans are. As for the counter I'm going to open a report for the issue. Do you know if its possible to do a pre code:before:selection { in any form? Then  I can make the selection background transparent for just the :before

Comment: @DrBrad That is unfortunate. I tried this, but as I wrote in my edit, the counter seems to be completely unaffected by any `::selection` styling whatsoever. I even tried triggering it by applying absolute positioning, z-index, 3D translation,... Nothing helped. Sorry.

Comment: No worries, I opened a report to chrome. I just thought maybe I was doing something wrong with the ::selection tag that may allow that to work.

Comment: @DrBrad Don't think you are :-) If you could link to the report, I (and others, when they see it) can track the report and star it so it gets some attention. Hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

It might not work because you forgot the prefixes:

```
pre code::before {
  content: counter(line);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

If that doesn't work:

```
pre code::before {
  content: counter(line);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Sadly the no change but highlight/selection start from the :before is no longer possible. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DrBrad I've edited the answer to include another solution